# Cast Youtube videos inside my Android app directly to Youtube (in chromecast or roku or tv)

Tags: android, google-chrome, chromecast, google-cast, android-cast-api

I am building an Android app with my youtube videos. I want to add casting support to these videos within my app. I don't want to build separate receiver app in chromecast but want to just use the existing youtube receiver app in chromecast/Roku..etc.
I am currently using 'Youtube Android Player' API to embed videos in my app but I can't find the cast support in-built. I am willing to move to just HTML5 youtube embedding if casting support works that way.

Would greatly appreciate if someone can suggest a way if they are able build such cast'ing support of youtube videos in their android app?

(I have researched internet and some of the 2013 & early '14 posts suggest it's not possible. Would like to know if anything has changed since then)

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no support in the Cast SDK to cast YT videos; some folks have used a custom receiver and have used embedded iframe to show YT videos but that is not a perfect solution and has issues; for example you cannot skip ads, etc.

Comment: Is status the same now in 2017?

Comment: Would also like to know the advised way to cast YouTube videos in 2017?